# How to change the colour of progressbar in WPF without loosing its style?

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I want to change the colour of progress bar in WPF. When I change the colour, it loses its style. How can one change colour keeping windows default style?

Comment: ProgressBar color is Foreground, and what color you about?

Answer (score 1):

1. Override the control template for the progress bar

This generates XAML code like:

```
<ProgressBar.Resources>
          <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
          <Border CornerRadius="2" Margin="1">
            <Border.Background>
              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#50FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.5385"/>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
          </Border>
          <Border BorderBrush="#80FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Margin="1">
            <Border.Background>
              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.25"/>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
          </Border>
          <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="1"/>
          <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1">
            <Grid x:Name="Foreground">
              <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
              <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="True">
                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Width="100">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="0.4"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
              </Grid>
              <Grid x:Name="Overlay">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition/>
                  <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="LeftDark" Margin="1,1,0,1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#0C000000" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.3"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>                          
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="RightDark" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,1,1,1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#20000000" Offset="0.7"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#0C000000" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="LeftLight" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1">
                      <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,0.5,0.5"/>
                      </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                      <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="CenterLight" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                      <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="RightLight" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
                  <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1">
                      <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,-0.5,0.5"/>
                      </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                      <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4" Offset="1"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                  </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Border x:Name="Highlight1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                  <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#90FFFFFF" Offset="0.5385"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.5385"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Highlight2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                  <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.05"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.25"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.Background>
                </Border>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Decorator>
          <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="TemplateRoot">
              <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LeftDark" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightDark" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LeftLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CenterLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightLight" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </Trigger>
          <!--<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Animation" Value="#80B5FFA9"/>
          </Trigger>-->
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ProgressBar.Resources>
```

2. Do the changes in template in case you need to change defaults
3. Define a data trigger and use setter to change the "foreground" property